# Combining results with different confidence levels

Tags: confidence-interval

I have an experiment where I throw a biased coin were with confidence interval [0.38, 0.42] and confidence level of 0.95 I will get heads. If I get heads then I throw a biased 6-sided die which gives me 1 with probability given in the interval [0.48, 0.52] and confidence level 0.90.

What is the probability of getting 1 and what is my confidence level for that result. If no intervals and no confidence levels the problem is trivial and could be done with simple multiplication, but I am pretty sure simple multiplication will not be a solution in interval case.

Comment: Hi Andre, I simplified the example in order to present it in "text book" style but at this point I have no idea whether this can be solved using off the shelve methods.

Answer (score 1):

A confidence interval is a "post-data" interval *estimate* that is supposed to bracket the true parameter in %C of the samples. What you appear to be trying to do is to *predict* a future event. For this, you need a little more structure on your problem. In particular, a confidence interval is insufficient. What you really need is a *distribution* of possible head probabilities and probabilities of rolling 1. Then, you need to calculate the probability as such:

Let $C$ be the outcome of the coin toss and $X$ be the results of the die roll, $f_H(p)$ isthe density function on the probability of heads (i.e., $p$) and $f_{1|C=H}(q)$ is the density function for the probability of rolling a 1 (i.e, $q$) given that you got a head. Therefore,

$P(X=1)=E[1_{C=H}1_{X=1|C=H}]=E[1_{C=H}]E[1_{X=1|C=H}]$ where $1_{C=H}$ and $1_{X=1|C=H}$ are indicator functions that take value 1 when the event in subscript happens, and 0 otherwise. Conditional independence between the coin toss and die roll allow you to multiply expected values.

Now, $E[1_{C=H}]E[1_{X=1|C=H}]=\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1pf_H(p)qf_{1|C=H}(q)dqdp$. In other words, you multiply the expected values of the distributions on P(heads) and P(X=1|Heads). So, you will need more info to solve your problem as formulated.

IF you have the underlying data that produced each CI, then you can use methods from [Bayesian prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Bayesian_prediction) or [predictive likelihood](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-5/issue-2/Predictive-Likelihood-A-Review/10.1214/ss/1177012175.full)

Comment: In fact I don't have the underlying data and I am only given the CI + CL. I know that the underlying distributions will follow Normal Distribution. I assume that if I have CI I can compute compute minimal probability of getting 1 (by taking lower bounds) but I am not sure what happens to CL of my result.

Comment: Ok, if you don't have the data, then ignore the last sentence. You cannot get a lower bound by using the lower limits of the CIs, as they are not 100% CIs. The underlying distributions cannot be normal, as P(Heads) and P(X=1) are bounded between 0 and 1. Do you know the most likely P(Heads) and P(X=1)? If not, then your problem is underdefined.

Comment: The only approach I can see for using only the intervals would be to rely on conditional independence of the coin and die and interpret the CI's and CL as *probability intervals*. In that case, you would multiply the interval endpoints and probabilities; i.e, $P((p\in [0.38, 0.42])\cap (q \in [0.48, 0.52])) = P(p\in [0.38, 0.42])P(q \in [0.48, 0.52])=P(P(X=1)\in [0.38\times.48,0.42\times0.52])\\$

Comment: P(X=1) cannot be calculated exactly without prior distributions on P(heads) and P(X=1|Heads)